# Question marks are inserted into my table in MySQL instead of Greek letters

Tags: mysql

I have a UTF-8 database in MySQL, I connected to the MySQL server using the MySQL client that comes with WampServer, and I entered the following in the MySQL client command line:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
use my_db;
INSERT INTO students VALUES('γεια');
```

But instead of having the Greek letters "γεια" inserted into the `students` table, four question marks were inserted ("????").

Note that I inserted the Greek letters "γεια" in phpMyAdmin and it worked.

I am using Windows.

Comment: Which client/sever version?

Comment: @danblack `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';` returns the version `5.6.17`, I think this is the server version, but I don't know how to get the client version.

Comment: `\s` on the prompt, do this because it displays server and client character set information ( or `mysql --version`).

Comment: See "question marks" (not black diamond) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored